# What total_amount in liquid gettxoutsetinfo command means?

Tags: liquid

`$ elements-cli gettxoutsetinfo muhash`

```json
{
  "height": 2655501,
  "bestblock": "5d52cd99233d96c5d99c1b80e2e04fcd068b83d0957095c6728bec98ca16c853",
  "txouts": 274112,
  "bogosize": 20056230,
  "muhash": "ef3fe8d1f94bc6360ea456fdcec78e30db123da2a996e01e1e73cea7500b287e",
  "total_amount": 29014665.56386005,
  "transactions": 177123,
  "disk_size": 38058240
}
```

`total_amount` here is ~`29,014,665`. The help section says "The total amount of coins in the UTXO set". But I see only "3,346.37 L-BTC in circulation" in the [Liquid.Network explorer](https://liquid.network/)

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be the sum of all outputs with explicit (unblinded) values across all assets (not just L-BTC).

This should be changed to something more meaningful with multiple/confidential assets.

https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements/blob/2d298f7e3f76bc6c19d9550af4fd1ef48cf0b2a6/src/node/coinstats.cpp#L90